# Jackson writeValueAsString: valid JSON not valid anymore

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some Strings, i want to create a valid JSON.

Input: timestamp, feature, id, data (is valid JSON itself)

`{"items":[{"id":"13123545","count": 5, "amount": 11.6},{"id": "1638343", "count": 1, "amount": 55.99}], "oid": 5556}`

```
    //Some code here
    valueItems.add(new ValueItem(timestamp, feature, id, data));
    valueData.setInformation(valueItems);
    valueString = valueMapper.writeValueAsString(valueData);
    System.out.println(valueString);
```

Output:

```
{
    "information": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2013-01-01",
            "feature": "login",
            "id": 0,
            "data": "{\"items\":[{\"id\":\"14737\",\"count\": 5, \"amount\": 11.6},{\"id\": \"1874345\", \"count\": 1, \"amount\": 55.99}], \"oid\": 5556}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON itself is valid, but the element of "data" is not valid JSON anymore due to the  . Why does this happen? How can i change it or prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean not valid?  `JSON.parse` works fine on it.  What does your ValueItem class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are representing JSON text as a `String`, and so all the quotes are escaped (i.e. with `\"`).

Why are you representing JSON in this way, internally in your Java program?  Generally, it makes more sense to maintain a pure-POJO internal representation and then translate all of that into JSON in one go, rather than mixing POJOs and JSON.

In your case, this would mean that the `data` field in your `Information` class should not be a `String`, but should instead be an object which is defined as containing `Set<Item> items` and `long oid`, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Wrote my own class, now everything looks fine :)